# FastApi OAuth2 with JWT Token not working

Tags: javascript, python, oauth-2.0, jwt, fastapi

I followed along with the FastApi Security guide here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/

I only made some changes to make it specific to me, like changing the username and password and secret key. This appears to work. When I add the `token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)` to my endpoints, I see they get locked down and I need to login to access them. However, I was doing testing on my frontend to pull some data from the databas, I found that I do not need to pass my token to the endpoint to access it. All I need to to pass `request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ')` and it works. I am very confused as to what I missed.
My understanding is that I should need to pass the token as well to get access to the endpoints. Something like: `request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + "TOKEN")`

Here is a sample endpoint and the JS code that accesses it.

```
@app.get("/Tables")
async def  tables(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    x = ("SHOW TABLES;")
    db = db_conn(x)
    return db

function tablesFunction(){
    console.log('Loading Tables');
    // console.log("token", tokenObj);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Tables', true) 
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer')
    request.onload = function () {
       Code that calls my db and displays the tables on the webpage
      }
      request.send()
}
```

As you can see in this above example, I am not passing in my token from logging in. But this still works. If I remove the setRequestHeader line, I do get an authorization error. Any help is appreciated, this is all brand new to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the standard oauth2_scheme as defined in the example, you're *just retrieving the token*.

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")
```

You're not doing anything with it. It's your job to verify that the token *is valid* and that the *user has access to the resource*.

In the examples it's usually used for `get_current_user`. The reason why it errors out when you don't include a header, is because the default behaviour of `OAuth2PasswordBearer` is that an `Authorization` header needs to be present at least (i.e. it has to be able to at least get some sort of token).

The [FastAPI example uses the following function](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/#handle-jwt-tokens) to decode and verify the JWT:

```py
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(fake_users_db, username=token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    return user
```

Your code is effectively just asking "is there a token present?" and nothing more.